i have problem with ckeditor5 in my angular application
I don't see the function to adjust font style, font size, font color in my ckeditor, what should I do?
The strings are related to the ckedotor I installed: "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^7.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^42.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^41.4.2",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "^42.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^42.0.0",
I'm new and don't know how to do it, can someone help me?
